# Array Values to assign the variables in php

Tags: php

Array Values to assign the variables in php:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 116249
                [Amount] => 51.62
                [Currency] => INR
                [ExchangeRate] => 1
                [InvoiceDate] => 2015-12-16T00:00:00Z
                }
       [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 116250
                [Amount] => 55.20
                [Currency] => KWD
                [ExchangeRate] => 1
                [InvoiceDate] => 2015-12-16T00:00:00Z
                }

       [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 116251
                [Amount] => 59.42
                [Currency] => USD
                [ExchangeRate] => 1
                [InvoiceDate] => 2015-12-16T00:00:00Z
                }  

    }

foreach ($invoice as $key => $value) 
{
        $Id=$value->Id;
        $Amount=$value->Amount;
        $Currency=$value->Currency;
        $ExchangeRate=$value->ExchangeRate;
        $invoiceDate = str_replace('Z', '', str_replace('T', ' ',$value->InvoiceDate)); 



 }            


  $jsonData ='[{"Id": "'.$Id.'",
                "Amount": "'.$Amount.'",
                "Currency": "'.$Currency.'",
                "ExchangeRate": "'.$ExchangeRate.'",
                "invoiceDate": "'.$invoiceDate.'"}];
```

I tried this code last array values only print array[2] values, I need Output like

```
[{"Id": "116249",
                    "Amount": "51.62",
                    "Currency": "INR",
                    "ExchangeRate": "1",
                    "invoiceDate": "2015-12-16T00:00:00Z"},

                    {"Id": "116250",
                    "Amount": "55.20",
                    "Currency": "KWD",
                    "ExchangeRate": "1",
                    "invoiceDate": "2015-12-16T00:00:00Z"},

                    {"Id": "116251",
                    "Amount": "59.42",
                    "Currency": "USD",
                    "ExchangeRate": "1",
                    "invoiceDate": "2015-12-16T00:00:00Z"}]
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: i need output like that

Comment: From what exactly? Can you edit your question to tell us what you have, what you are doing and your problem?

Comment: Sorry, don't have us drag everything out of you. _Be precise in your question_:  what is your input, what is the desired output. Is your question really just "how do I create a json string from an array"?

Comment: i tried that code last array values only printing

Comment: @arkascha his json string isn't looping through. He's not generating a json array by using json_encode on the array. He's manually entering the data into a json style string. Just looked at the code and got what he was doing.

Comment: {"Id": "116251",
                    "Amount": "59.42",
                    "Currency": "USD",
                    "ExchangeRate": "1",
                    "invoiceDate": "2015-12-16T00:00:00Z"}

Comment: @Liam Sorsby  thats correct

Comment: @Balu instead of manually creating the json string and looping through just run json_encode on your $invoice variable

Comment: sorry i am new please explain clearly some example

Comment: @Balu please see answer.

Comment: its possible for that previous code in looping

Comment: i have array of array values in full coding part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Liam that `json_encode()` is probably the best solution for your issue. However, if you are looking for a DIY solution, it's pretty simple:

```
$jsonData = '[';
foreach ($invoice as $key => $value) 
{
        $Id=$value->Id;
        $Amount=$value->Amount;
        $Currency=$value->Currency;
        $ExchangeRate=$value->ExchangeRate;
        $invoiceDate = str_replace('Z', '', str_replace('T', ' ',$value->InvoiceDate)); 

        // Append the next invoice's JSON data to all of the JSON data
        $jsonData .='{"Id": "'.$Id.'",
                "Amount": "'.$Amount.'",
                "Currency": "'.$Currency.'",
                "ExchangeRate": "'.$ExchangeRate.'",
                "invoiceDate": "'.$invoiceDate.'"},';

 }

 // Clean up and close off the JSON data:
 $jsonData = rtrim($jsonData, ','); // remove the trailing comma
 $jsonData .= ']'; // Add the closing bracket.
```

The issue you were having in your code was that you were only assigning the JSON data once, after the foreach loop ran. Instead, you would need to append each invoice's JSON data with the other invoices' JSON data.

Nonetheless, `json_encode()` is probably the better solution because it's one line, easier to read, and arguably easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your wanting to create a json string from an array. All you need to do is run the following

```
jsonData = json_encode($invoice);
```

If your wanting to create the array using a loop to generate specific values only then you can do the following:

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($invoice as $key => $value) 
{
   $tmp["id"] = $value->Id;
   $tmp["amount"] = $value->Amount;
   $tmp["Currency"] = $value->Currency;
   $tmp["ExchangeRate"] = $value->ExchangeRate;
   $tmp["invoiceDate"] = str_replace('Z', '', str_replace('T','',$value->InvoiceDate));
 }  

jsonData = json_encode($tmp);
```

*** Edit ***

If your using a mysql date for the invoiceData variable. Then you would be better to use the PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: brother, i think its json_encode() .not jsone_encode() :)